# How to control node labels in Sankey diagram

Tags: r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I have a Sankey diagram I'm creating in R.  It produces the diagram but the node names are placed on the left of the nodes for the right side nodes.  I would like all names to be on the right so the real names (which are longer) don't overlap with each other.

Below is a complete set of working code that will generate the diagram I am currently working with.

```
library(networkD3)

nodes <- data.frame('name' = 
c('Node0','Node1','Node2','Node3','Node4','Node5','Node6',                   
'Node7','Node8','Node9','Node10','Node11','Node12','Node13',
'Node14','Node15','Node16','Node17','Node18','Node19',
'Node20','Node21','Node22','Node23','Node24','Node25',
'Node26','Node27','Node28','Node29','Node30','Node31',
'Node32','Node33'))

links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
  0, 3,140,
  0, 4,140,
  0, 5,140,
  0, 6,140,
  1, 3,140,
  1, 4,140,
  1, 5,140,
  1, 6,140,
  2, 3,140,
  2, 4,140,
  2, 5,140,
  2, 6,140,
  3, 7,130,
  3, 8,130,
  3, 9,50,
  3,10,50,
  3,11,50,
  4,12,140,
  4,13,100,
  4,14,100,
  4,15,80,
  5,16,150,
  5,17,150,
  5,18,60,
  5,19,60,
  6,20,180,
  6,21,80,
  6,22,80,
  6,23,80,
  7,24,13,
  7,33,13,
  7,31,104,
  8,24,13,
  8,33,13,
  8,26,52,
  8,27,52,
  9,24,10,
  9,33,10,
  9,29,30,
  9,30,30,
  10,24,10,
  10,33,10,
  10,29,30,
  10,30,30,
  11,24,10,
  11,33,10,
  11,29,30,
  11,30,30,
  12,24,16,
  12,33,16,
  12,26,36,
  12,27,36,
  12,28,36,
  13,24,10,
  13,33,10,
  13,26,30,
  13,27,30,
  13,28,30,
  14,24,10,
  14,33,10,
  14,26,30,
  14,27,30,
  14,28,30,
  15,24,10,
  15,33,10,
  15,31,60,
  16,24,30,
  16,33,30,
  16,32,90,
  17,24,30,
  17,33,30,
  17,32,90,
  18,24,10,
  18,33,10,
  18,25,40,
  19,24,30,
  19,33,30,
  20,24,90,
  20,33,90,
  21,33,80,
  22,24,10,
  22,33,10,
  22,29,30,
  22,30,30,
  23,24,40,
  23,33,40),
byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize= 15, nodeWidth = 20,
              colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the text-anchor after creating the sankey network plot by adding some JavaScript using the htmlwidgets package. You may also want to adjust the left margin if you want the text to be on right side of the right side nodes.

```
library(htmlwidgets)

sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                    Source = "source", Target = "target",
                    Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                    fontSize= 15, nodeWidth = 20, margin = list(left = 100),
                    colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);"))

onRender(
  sn,
  '
  function(el, x) {
    d3.selectAll(".node text").attr("text-anchor", "begin").attr("x", 20);
  }
  '
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I tried upvoting your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.  This did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: When a sankey plot is in a tab (other than the first), (using https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#tabbed_sections), the above method does not work. Do you happen to know a way to overcome that problem?

Comment: create a new question with a minimal reproducible example and I'll take a look at

Comment: Here is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509228/adjusting-sankey-plot-in-tabbed-section